# here maps API JS clustering: need relative values instead number of clustered weight

Tags: javascript, text, cluster-analysis, here-api

*using: Maps API for Javascript*

I am looking for a solution to display the relative value of the clustered points (i.e. 50%).

The case is to display GPS locations with numbers of events as weight. So it shows the points with the number in the circle. However, I would like to show the relative number. 100% is the sum of all events on the global map, which is easy to be calculated. This also includes values below 1, i.e. 0.01%.
My first simple approach was to reduce the %-sign, but for clustering, the minimum value is 1, or?

I am thankful for any help.

```
var dataPoints = [];
dataPoints.push(new H.clustering.DataPoint(51.01, 2.01, 10.1234567890));
dataPoints.push(new H.clustering.DataPoint(49.31, 2.01, 20));
dataPoints.push(new H.clustering.DataPoint(50.34, 1.81, 0.1));
dataPoints.push(new H.clustering.DataPoint(53.00, 1.71, 4.3));
dataPoints.push(new H.clustering.DataPoint(52.61, 2.01, 5.3));

var clusteredDataProvider = new H.clustering.Provider(dataPoints);

// Create a layer that includes the data provider and its data points: 
var layer = new H.map.layer.ObjectLayer(clusteredDataProvider);

// Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
// In your own code, replace variable window.apikey with your own apikey
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  apikey: window.apikey
});

var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

// Step2: initialize a map
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'), defaultLayers.vector.normal.map, {
  center: new H.geo.Point(50, 1),
  zoom: 6,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});
// add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());

// Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Step 4: create the default UI component, for displaying bubbles
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

// Add the layer to the map:
map.addLayer(layer);

dataPoints.push(new H.clustering.DataPoint(52.45, 1.01, 0.05));
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to create your custom clustering theme:

```js
// ....

var clusteredDataProvider = new H.clustering.Provider(dataPoints, {
    theme: customTheme
  });

customTheme = {
  getClusterPresentation: function(cluster) {
    // here you create your cluster Marker with custom Icon
  },
  getNoisePresentation: function (noisePoint) {
    // here you create your noise point Marker with custom Icon
  }
};

// ....
```

I created simple [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nwu1pz2c/) example using your data which shows relative values as percentage. Hope it helps.

More information about custom theme for clustering: [API Reference](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.clustering.ITheme.html) & [HERE example](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/clustering/custom-cluster-theme)